# How to change tick limit and frequency for seaborn figure-level plots (FacetGrid)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

my image is  too dense like above. I would like to increase xticks range(ig, 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4). Please let me know how.

```
facet = sns.lmplot(data = df, x='x', y='y', hue='label', fit_reg=False, legend = True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the figure size with the `height` and `aspect` properties. Use `ax.set_xticks` to set the desired x-axis tick limits and frequency. The same can be done for the y-axis by using `ax.set_yticks`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(365)  # only for repeatability of the sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,high=100,size=(1000,2)),columns=['x','y'])
facet  = sns.lmplot(x='x',y='y',data=df,height=6, aspect=2)
facet.ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 101, 5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

- With `facet.ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 101, 10))`

[image]